# Exception in thread "main @coroutine#2" java.lang.NullPointerException in ViewModelTest?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, mockito-kotlin

I have wrote unit testing in ViewModel with coroutines with mockito. class but I am getting following exception

```
 Exception in thread "main @coroutine#2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModel$getGifsFromText$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModel.kt:24)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.dispatch(MainTestDispatcher.kt:35)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:305)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:27)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:49)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModel.getGifsFromText(GiphyTaskViewModel.kt:22)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:61)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest.onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.TestCoroutineRule$apply$1.evaluate(TaskCoroutineRule.kt:22)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)


java.lang.RuntimeException: Method getMainLooper in android.os.Looper not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.

    at android.os.Looper.getMainLooper(Looper.java)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:486)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:224)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:63)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:274)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:84)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest.onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
    at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.TestCoroutineRule$apply$1.evaluate(TaskCoroutineRule.kt:22)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:42)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

below my ViewModel class where I have implemented viewmodel logic

```
 @HiltViewModel
class GiphyTaskViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val giphyTaskRepository: GiphyTaskRepository):ViewModel()
{
    var giphyresponse = MutableLiveData<Result<List<DataItem>?>>()



    fun getGifsFromText(apikey:String,text:String,limit:Int)= viewModelScope.launch {
        giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit).let { response->
            if(response?.isSuccessful){
                var list=response.body()?.data
                giphyresponse.postValue(Success(list))
            }else{
                Error(Exception(response.message()))

            }

        }
    }

}
```

below Repository  class

```
class GiphyTaskRepository
@Inject
constructor(private val giphyTaskApiService: GiphyTaskApiService)
{

    suspend fun getGifsFromText(apikey:String,text:String,limit:Int)=
        giphyTaskApiService.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit)
}
```

below interface class

interface GiphyTaskApiService {

```
    @GET("gifs/search")
    suspend fun getGifsFromText(
        @Query("api_key") api_key:String,
        @Query("q") q:String ,
        @Query("limit") limit:Int
    ):Response<GiphyResponse>
}
```

below my ViewModel test class

```
 @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class GiphyTaskViewModelTest {







    @Mock
    private lateinit var apiUsersObserver: Observer<Result<List<DataItem>?>>


    @RegisterExtension
    @JvmField
    @get:Rule
    val testInstantTaskExecutorRule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
   val testCoroutineRule = TestCoroutineRule()
    @Mock
     var giphyTaskViewModel:GiphyTaskViewModel? = null

    @Mock
     lateinit var  giphyTaskRepository:GiphyTaskRepository








    @Before
     fun setUp() {


        /* Create a mock response */;
        /* Create a mock response */;


                giphyTaskViewModel = GiphyTaskViewModel(giphyTaskRepository)
        }

    @Test
    fun onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData() {
        runBlockingTest {



            val response: Response<GiphyResponse> = mock()


            giphyTaskViewModel?.getGifsFromText(Constants.Api_Key,"text", Constants.Limit)
           `when`(giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(Constants.Api_Key,"text", Constants.Limit)).thenReturn(response)
            giphyTaskViewModel?.giphyresponse?.observeForever(apiUsersObserver)
            assertNotNull(giphyTaskViewModel?.giphyresponse?.value)




        }
    }



}
```

What I have tried

1.[I have tried following link][1]

2. I have rewrite Viewmodel logic but I am getting following exception
   xception in thread "main @coroutine#2" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModel$getGifsFromText$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModel.kt:26)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.test.internal.TestMainDispatcher.dispatch(MainTestDispatcher.kt:35)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:305)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:27)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:49)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModel.getGifsFromText(GiphyTaskViewModel.kt:24)
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:82)
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invoke(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt)
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invoke(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:305)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:27)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:84)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:45)
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest.onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:75)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
   at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
   at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.TestCoroutineRule$apply$1.evaluate(TaskCoroutineRule.kt:22)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
   at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
   at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
   at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
   at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
   at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
   at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
   at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)

java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.arch.core.executor.DefaultTaskExecutor.isMainThread(DefaultTaskExecutor.java:77)
at androidx.arch.core.executor.ArchTaskExecutor.isMainThread(ArchTaskExecutor.java:116)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:486)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:224)
at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:84)
at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invoke(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt)
at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invoke(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt$runBlockingTest$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:50)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher.dispatch(TestCoroutineDispatcher.kt:50)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:305)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:27)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async(Builders.common.kt:91)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.async$default(Builders.common.kt:84)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.async$default(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:49)
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:45)
at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest.onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:75)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:54)
at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.TestCoroutineRule$apply$1.evaluate(TaskCoroutineRule.kt:22)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:99)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:105)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:40)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake what I have to inorder to pass the tests successfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that you're invoking a method on a null object, `giphyTaskRepository` if I'm not mistaken. I would guess that `MockitoJUnitRunner` isn't detecting your `lateinit` fields. I haven't used Mockito in conjunction with Kotlin before so I can't be sure

Comment: @Jeroen Steenbeeke what is your suggestion then

Comment: I think that not case if you checkother places I am also lateinit fields

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your `@Before` method and check the field values? Might simply be that Mockito doesn't set them until after these are run. Again, I haven't used Mockito with Kotlin before so I'm guessing at this point (hence my commenting rather than posting an answer)

Comment: I have put break point @JeroenSteenbeeke, and debug is passing there are exception occurring DispatchedContinuation[BlockingEventLoop@59221b97, Continuation at com.example.giphyandroidapp.viewmodel.GiphyTaskViewModelTest$onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData$1.invokeSuspend(GiphyTaskViewModelTest.kt:62)@1c05a54d]

Comment: So `giphyTaskRepository` is not null? Then I think your method call `getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit)` is returning null due to that being the Mockito default for mocked classes. You need to specify what the method should return (i.e. `when(giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(/* some value */`)

Comment: @Jeroen can you explain your example in answer form))

Comment: I could, but I'm not entirely sure my hunch is correct.

Comment: instead of verify I  have to use when you mean

Comment: No in addition to. You use `when()` to specify how the mock should behave, and `verify()` to check if certain methods are called

Comment: I am not sure why it is failing when I have initialized allrepository and viewmodelclass

Comment: You're using mocks (through the `@Mock` annotation), these are dummy versions of your classes that return `null` on every call by default

Answer (score 3):

What I believe is happening is that your mocked version of `GiphyTaskRepository` is exhibiting the default Mockito behavior of returning `null` for all methods that do not have explicitly specified behavior.

As such, your call `giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(apikey,text,limit)` in `GiphyTaskViewModel` returns `null`, causing the subsequent call to `let` to throw a NullPointerException.

To avoid this, you need to explicitly specify what this method should return, for instance in your `setUp` method:

```kotlin
@Before
fun setUp() {
  val response: Response<GiphyResponse> = /* Create a mock response */;
  when(giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(any(),any(),any())).thenReturn(response);

  giphyTaskViewModel = GiphyTaskViewModel(giphyTaskRepository)
}
```

However, since you are using coroutines, it gets a bit trickier. You should include the `mockito-kotlin` library:

```
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:x.x.x"
```

Next, both the `GiphyTaskRepository` and the method `getGifsFromText` need to be declared `open` for the mocking to work.

Finally, you need to go about stubbing a bit differently:

```kotlin
@Before
fun setUp() = runBlocking { // This bit is important
  val response: Response<GiphyResponse> = /* Create a mock response */;
  given(giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(any(),any(),any())).willSuspendableAnswer {
                response
            }
  giphyTaskViewModel = GiphyTaskViewModel(giphyTaskRepository)

  Unit 
}
```

I believe your test method will then succeed

Comment: but when(giphyTaskRepository.getGifsFromText(any(),any(),any())).thenReturn(response) can be used only in  fun onCreation_fetchUserApiCalled_dataSavedToLiveData()

Comment: Whichever you prefer. The `when` statement can be put either in the setup method or in the test method

Comment: yes but I will call that method I am getting following error warning Suspend function 'getGifsFromText' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Comment: I see. It appears you need to do some extra work to use mocks with coroutines: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/pull/357

Comment: can you suggest other ways

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: can you check my updated post I have improved my post I have tried as you told

Comment: I've updated my answer to showcase how to setup a mock for a suspend function (took some research to figure out). That said, you should probably do all given/when statements _prior_ to calling GiphyTaskViewModel's constructor.

Comment: thankyou for your answer but my tests are still failing